# Why code doesn't redirect to login page when password is updated?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Here is the problem everything work token change password is updated but when click on button, button don't redirect page to login page so if someone got solution for this problem.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FaFingerprint } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useNewPasswordMutation } from '../Redux/Api/userApiSlice'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

import '../styles/Login.css'
import { setCredentials } from '../Redux/Api/authSlice'


export default function ResetPassword() {

    const [newPasswword, setNewPassword] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [newPassword] = useNewPasswordMutation()
    const { addNewPassword } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (addNewPassword)
            navigate('/login')

    }, [navigate, addNewPassword])

    const newPasswordHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            const res = await newPassword({ password }).unwrap()
            dispatch(setCredentials({ ...res }))
            dispatch(addNewPassword({ ...res }))
            navigate('/login')
        } catch (err) {
            toast.error(err?.data?.message || err.error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row w-500">
                <div className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                    <div className="login-card card-block auth-body">
                        <div className="authbox">
                            <div className="brand-logo text-center">Bubllee</div>
                            <p className='text-secondary text-center' style={{ fontFamily: 'Indie Flower', fontSize: '12px' }} >Please enter your new password</p>
                            <br />
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <form action="" className='w-100' onSubmit={newPasswordHandler}>
                                    <div className="input-group">
                                        <span className='input-group-addon'>
                                            <FaFingerprint className='icon iconfont' />
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="password" placeholder='Enter New Password' className='form-control' required autoComplete='off'
                                            value={newPasswword} onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.target.value)} style={{ borderRadius: '20px' }} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="links text-right ">
                                        <div className="registration-link">
                                            <p>Go back to</p>
                                            <Link to='/' className='text-left f-w-600'>
                                                <p className='iconfont iconfont-lock'>Sign In</p>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div className="m-t-20">
                                        <button type='submit' className="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block m-b-10 signupbtn">Update Password</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

I tried everything change the routes `useNavigate` but in console log I got new token for password but page doesn't redirect when password is updated

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to extract redux action from `useSelector`. **useSelector** returns state value from redux store. You cannot dispatch using a state value as dispatch action.

Comment: thanks on your answer i change useSelector with useDispatch but still doesn't rendering to login page can u tell me if there is got some link with similar problem and how to fix it

Comment: If your `addNewPassword` is an action then import it directly like you imported the `setCredentials`. No need to import it via `useDispatch`

Comment: now it's redirecting but in home page not to login i try to put this also but also is redirecting to home page   useEffect(() => {
        if (addNewPassword.value)
            window.location.replace('/')

    }, [navigate, addNewPassword])